# Docusign REST API Error : This Account lacks sufficient permissions

Tags: docusignapi

Everything is working well when using the demo API. I followed the "go live" procedure, the API key is now 'live' and I updated all the settings for production.

When creating the envelope I receive this error message :

```
{"errorCode"=>"ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS", "message"=>"This Account lacks sufficient permissions."}
```

I tried to set embedded argument to false on the json but apparently it's not doing anything different.

```
{:embedded => false,:name => "XXX yyy",:email => "XXX@yyy.com",:role_name => "Propriétaire", :sign_here_tabs => ... }
```

Any idea on how to solve this ? Thanks !

EDIT : here is the JSON request :

```
    {
      "emailBlurb": "deijzed",
      "emailSubject": "dzeidjezij",
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentId": "1",
          "name": "2017-11-09_21h_50m_52s.pdf"
        }
      ],
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "accessCode": "",
            "addAccessCodeToEmail": false,
            "customFields": null,
            "idCheckConfigurationName": null,
            "idCheckInformationInput": null,
            "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration": false,
            "note": null,
            "phoneAuthentication": null,
            "recipientAttachment": null,
            "requireIdLookup": null,
            "roleName": "Propri\u00c3\u00a9taire",
            "routingOrder": 1,
            "socialAuthentications": null,
            "recipientId": 1,
            "email": "xxx@company.com",
            "name": "xxx yyy",
            "autoNavigation": false,
            "defaultRecipient": false,
            "signatureInfo": null,
            "tabs": {
              "approveTabs": null,
              "checkboxTabs": [
                {
                }
              ],
              "companyTabs": null,
              "dateSignedTabs": [

              ],
              "dateTabs": null,
              "declineTabs": null,
              "emailTabs": [

              ],
              "envelopeIdTabs": null,
              "fullNameTabs": [

              ],
              "listTabs": [

              ],
              "noteTabs": null,
              "numberTabs": [

              ],
              "radioGroupTabs": [
                {
                }
              ],
              "initialHereTabs": [
                {

                }
              ],
              "signHereTabs": [
                {
                }
              ],
              "signerAttachmentTabs": null,
              "ssnTabs": null,
              "textTabs": [
                {

                }],
              "titleTabs": [

              ],
              "zipTabs": null
            }
          },
          {
            "accessCode": "",
            "addAccessCodeToEmail": false,
            "customFields": null,
            "idCheckConfigurationName": null,
            "idCheckInformationInput": null,
            "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration": false,
            "note": null,
            "phoneAuthentication": null,
            "recipientAttachment": null,
            "requireIdLookup": null,
            "roleName": "company",
            "routingOrder": 2,
            "socialAuthentications": null,
            "recipientId": 2,
            "email": "xxx@yyy.com",
            "name": "xxx yyy",
            "autoNavigation": false,
            "defaultRecipient": false,
            "signatureInfo": null,
            "tabs": {
              "approveTabs": null,
              "checkboxTabs": [

              ],
              "companyTabs": null,
              "dateSignedTabs": [
                {
                }
              ],
              "dateTabs": null,
              "declineTabs": null,
              "emailTabs": [

              ],
              "envelopeIdTabs": null,
              "fullNameTabs": [

              ],
              "listTabs": [

              ],
              "noteTabs": null,
              "numberTabs": [

              ],
              "radioGroupTabs": [

              ],
              "initialHereTabs": [
                {
                }
              ],
              "signHereTabs": [
                {

                }
              ],
              "signerAttachmentTabs": null,
              "ssnTabs": null,
              "textTabs": [

              ],
              "titleTabs": [

              ],
              "zipTabs": null
            }
          }
        ],
        "carbonCopies": [

        ]
      },
      "eventNotification": {
        "useSoapInterface": false,
        "includeCertificateWithSoap": false,
        "url": "xxxxx",
        "loggingEnabled": true,
        "envelopeEvents": [

        ],
        "recipientEvents": [
          {
            "includeDocuments": true,
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
          }
        ]
      },
      "status": "sent",
      "customFields": null
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the envelope creation JSON, it seems you are using a feature in the envelope creation which is not available in your PROD account

Comment: sure, I've updated my message with the JSON request. I've removed all the tabs infos otherwise it would have been too long. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on my side : the API endpoint to be used for European accounts is not www.docusign but eu.docusign

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using "eventNotification", so can you please check if DocuSign connect is supported in your subscription/plan which you bought with DocuSign. If its not available then you need to contact your DocuSign Account Manager for enabling this feature.